# iOS app crash in TestFlight after some weeks working fine

Tags: react-native, expo, testflight

have you had the following error in TestFlight? Basically, we have test versions in TestFlight that when we launch them to external testers work. But it has happened to us 2 times that after a week or two, that version stops working.

Basically, the app won't open, won't even show the splash, and crashes.

Last week the app stopped working for all testers, we updated to a new version and it started working fine for them again. But yesterday the version that already works previously began to fail them again.

Today, I just generated a new version with no code changes and it works. But I'm afraid it will eventually start to fail.

When I say that it fails, it is that the app icon is touched, it tries to open, but it does not open and it crashes.

For example, now the new version works fine for me, but if I go to TestFlight and install a previous version that worked fine on my phone 2 days ago, it no longer works for me.

Any idea what could be going on, guys?
Maybe some certificate expires or I don't know, any idea is welcome.

I'm using `expo` managed workflow and `eas build` to generate the iOS app.

Something that happens with the versions that start to fail is that when they are installed, the first time it does not fail. But if I completely close the app and reopen it again, it doesn't open anymore, and the crash occurs.

We're using Sentry, but we don't have any issues. But I have this crash in TestFlight errors.

[image]

Thank you in advance for all your comments or ideas.

Comment: Apple had a cert expire last week - maybe related https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/704207

Comment: Yes, I had that problem last week and I solved it by creating new provisioning profiles.